# Batch file to copy folder structure

Tags: windows, batch

I want write a batch file that can copy a folder structure. This batch file would copy all folders in the source directory to the destination directory - the files themselves would not be copied.

For example, say there is a folder `src` with the following structure:

```
src
src\a\file1
src\a\file2
src\a\b\file1
src\c
```

The tool would create a `dest` folder like the following:

```
dest
dest\a
dets\a\b
dest\c
```

Is it possible to accomplish this task using a batch file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
XCopy "src" "dest" /T
```

Just make sure it's not cyclical.

To include empty directories, add /E:

```
XCopy "src" "dest" /T /E
```

Comment: It copies files too, I only want directory structure to be copied.

Comment: First post is corrected.

Comment: You can also add the `/E` switch which causes empty directories to be mirrored, too.

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't involve installing 3rd party programs.

Comment: I consistently use ROBOCOPY over XCOPY.  It is much more flexible and 100% superset of XCOPY.  see @Woody answer (2012 if you have things sorted by age)

Answer (score 4):

```
robocopy src dest /e /create
```

This partially achieves what you need. It will copy the directory structure and create zero length files as placeholders for the actual files. See more details [here](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

Answer (score 4):

not a batch file but **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)** can do this (with a little trick):

copy a directory and use the '**Only files of this type**' option. enter ***.nonsense** (or any other non-existent file extension) in this field.

now Total Commander will create the **entire directory structure** of the source folder at the destination without copying any files.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the file structure without the zero length files then it's

`robocopy src dest /e /create /xf *.*`

or

`robocopy src dest /mir /create /xf *.*`

Answer (score 1):

you can just put `|*.*` into Total commander copy dialog and the folder structure will be copied without files

Comment: put |*.* in the "only files of this type" box

Answer (score -2):

Check [47 folders app](http://47foldersapp.com/) , can create & copy folders structures in visual way..